# Tables: Entire Row as Link but with other Action buttons in the row as well

Tags: data-tables, best-practice

I'm trying to figure out what the best pattern or solution for this would be.

Basically, I have a table that will display rows and rows of items. The idea is that each row represents a data-entry, which is viewed in a new tab/window upon clicking the row itself.

However, I'd like to give users some affordances to allow them to easily delete the entries.

The common solution I see is to put a checkbox at the left of each row, and there's a separate button to apply an action (e.g. delete) to the selected rows. This lends itself well to batch-actions, but is kinda awkward if the expectation is that the user will only do said action to one row at a time.

So I was thinking of adding a Delete button to each row--but would this be awkward since hovering and clicking over the entire row will lead to the primary action (open link), but there'll be a button *inside* that row that leads to another action (delete)?

[image: Assume hovering and clicking over each row will open a link, but the trash icon is a different action]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing in the question already exists in even more complex situations like in e-mail client applications. One of the most complete, where you can get ideas is Gmail, with row selections, simple or multiple actions, and buttons when hovering over it with the mouse in the desktop version or with a double tap in the mobile version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!